# Connection reset by peer whilie downloading data with bulkloader

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to download data from a local development server (so that I can eventually upload it to a deployed application) using GAE's bulkloader.  During the download, I am receiving a "Connection reset by peer" error.  If I repeatedly try again, it rarely completes without error.  The dev server I am downloading from is a Java application.  To download the data, I am using the Python API version 1.6.5.  So what is going on here?

```
$ ./appcfg.py download_data --email=admin@test.com --passin --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api --filename=myapp_ContentEntity --kind=ContentEntity
Downloading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20120505.013522
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Password for admin@test.com: .
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20120505.013522.sql3
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20120505.013522.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api
[INFO    ] Downloading kinds: ['ContentEntity']
.........................................[ERROR   ] [WorkerThread-4] WorkerThread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/adaptive_thread_pool.py", line 176, in WorkOnItems
    status, instruction = item.PerformWork(self.__thread_pool)
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 764, in PerformWork
    transfer_time = self._TransferItem(thread_pool)
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1170, in _TransferItem
    self, retry_parallel=self.first)
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1471, in GetEntities
    results = self._QueryForPbs(query)
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1428, in _QueryForPbs
    result_pb)
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 308, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 248, in MakeSyncCall
    handler(request, response)
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 262, in _Dynamic_RunQuery
    'datastore_v3', 'RunQuery', query, query_result)
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 177, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 189, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 366, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/throttle.py", line 526, in http_response
    self.AddResponse(BANDWIDTH_DOWN, res)
  File "/home/spider/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/throttle.py", line 462, in AddResponse
    content = res.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 329, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(rbufsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 538, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 353, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
..[INFO    ] An error occurred. Shutting down...
.........[ERROR   ] Error in WorkerThread-4: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

[INFO    ] Have 388 entities, 0 previously transferred
[INFO    ] 388 entities (5989622 bytes) transferred in 22.5 seconds
```